# How do I install Bugzilla using XAMPP in Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, xampp, bugzilla

I need to install Bugzilla using XAMPP with Perl on my Windows XP machine. What is the procedure?

I have installed PHP based applications in XAMPP like Joomla, WordPress, etc., but it seems that Bugzilla is Perl based. Its installation guide is saying that I need to install ActivePerl. Do I need to do so since XAMPP comes with Perl addon?

Should I be keeping the source files in htdocs itself or is there any other folder for Perl applications?

I am totally new to Perl and honestly have no idea about it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, XAMPP contains ActivePerl, so you can try using ppm utility to install modules. Or just use cpan shell. `cpan Bundle::Bugzilla` will help at start.

Answer (score 1):

did you look at this document already?

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32Install

Comment: The documentation linked to hear does not talk about XAMPP, but Windows 32-bit in general. The question is asking about XAMPP and specifically if it has existing support for ActivePerl.